# PHP File Upload Then Show Download link

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using the simple script below to upload a zip file via php and then unzip it on my server.

The file will be a zipped folder. When the upload is complete I want to echo a link to the new folder.

So for instance if I upload a zip file containing a folder called "bar", after the success message I want to echo "http://foo.com/bar".

Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php
if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
$filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
$source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
$type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

$name = explode(".", $filename);
$accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed',
'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
    if($mime_type == $type) {
        $okay = true;
        break;
    } 
}

$continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
if(!$continue) {
    $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
}

$target_path = "/home/var/foo.com/".$filename;  // change this to the correct    
site     path
if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $x = $zip->open($target_path);
    if ($x === true) {
        $zip->extractTo("/home/var/foo.com/"); // change this to the correct site path
        $zip->close();

        unlink($target_path);
    }
    $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
} else {    
    $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1   
/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct and well-written. What exactly is the problem that you are trying to resolve? Does this code display any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick glance over everything, I'd say

```
$message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked. <a href=\"http://domain.com".$filename."\">Files</a>";
```

from what I gather on your script your telling it to upload directly to the servers directory path of the domain. Appending `$filename` as the folder name to that path so it creates a folder as such accordingly. From that its hardcoding the domain like you would to any other link and then appending the same filename variable to the end of it so it shows the same folder you just uploaded to.

This is just my guess overall though again only taking a quick glance and all.

Answer (score 0):

From a detailed look at your code, I would say that I can give a few comments:

1) You should use mkdir() to create a new directory in the uploads directory of your site (I assume it's the root in this case).

2) You don't need to move uploaded file before unzipping it. Simply unzip it into the newly created directory. Make sure there isn't already another directory with the same name. The uploaded file should be deleted automatically by PHP, so no need to unlink.

3) In reference to:

```
$name = explode(".", $filename);
```

What happens if the filename has more than one dot? You should really use substr() with strrpos() to get everything after the last dot.

4) After uploading, just echo the path http://www.yoursite.com/newdir - don't see the problem. If you can be more specific about what you are having difficulty with, please comment.